# How to get previous and next record order by date?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to get previous and next news order by date. The code below works fine if there is only one news a day. But cannot handle multiple news on the same day.

**NewsController.php**

```
public function detail($slug){
    $news = \App\News::active()->where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
    
    $prev_news = \App\News::whereDate('date', '>', $news->date)->active()->orderBy('date', 'desc')->first();
    
    $next_news = \App\News::whereDate('date', '<', $news->date)->active()->orderBy('date', 'desc')->first();
}
```

**web.php**

```
 Route::get('/news/{slug}', 'NewsController@detail')->name('news');
```

Thanks

Comment: Use [simple-pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination#simple-pagination)

Comment: @brombeer Not sure how to do that. I need the route like `/news/{slug}` and without any query params like `page=1`

Comment: Ok, that's info you might want to put in your question.

Comment: Unless I'm completely missing something: `$news` is a single news. Getting `$news->whereDate(...` should return nothing. It should probably be `\App\News::whereDate(...` in your last two lines

Comment: @brombeer Oh, you are right. Let me update the question. Thanks.

Comment: Don't edit your original (nonfunctional) code. Have you tried the (now edited) code? Does it even work?

Comment: @brombeer The (now edited) code is exactly what I want to ask. I had a typo on the original code. For example there have 3 news on today and I visiting the latest one. The next news will get from yesterday or earlier and skipped 2 today news. That is the problem of (now edited) code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
$news = \App\News::active()->where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();

$prev_news = \App\News::withDescription()->where(function($query) use($news){
    $query->where(function($query) use($news){
        $query->whereDate('date', $news->date)->where('id', '<', $news->id);
    })->orWhereDate('date', '>', $news->date);
})->online()->orderBy('date', 'asc')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->active()->first();

$next_news = \App\News::withDescription()->where(function($query) use($news){
    $query->where(function($query) use($news){
        $query->whereDate('date', $news->date)->where('id', '>', $news->id);
    })->orWhereDate('date', '<', $news->date);
})->online()->orderBy('date', 'desc')->orderBy('id', 'asc')->active()->first();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$prev_news = $news->whereDate('date', '>', $news->date)->active()->orderBy('date', 'desc')->get();

$next_news = $news->whereDate('date', '<', $news->date)->active()->orderBy('date', 'desc')->get();
```

you used ->first();
this only returns 1 value. so change it up to get()

Comment: Thanks. I just updated the question. There were some typos before.